# Why do bars appear with "inverted values"? d3.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to learn how to use d3.js in react, but something is wrong in my code.

I'm doing a bar chart, but the value of bar are "inverted", for example, a bar has a value of 30% but in the chart, the bar appears with 70% (like, 100% - 30% = 70%).
**How can I fix that?**

Here is my code: [codeSandBox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-tree-b183y)

Other question that I have is: **how can I change the height of bars?** I want to add some margin-top to show everything of the y Axis, but if I do that, the bars still with the same height and don't match with yAxis value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're swapping the `y` and `height` logic, it should be:

```
.attr("y", d => yScale(d.percent))
.attr("height", d => height - margin.bottom - margin.top - yScale(d.percent))
```

Or, if you set the working height as...

```
height = totalHeight - margin.bottom - margin.top
```

... it can be just:

```
.attr("y", d => yScale(d.percent))
.attr("height", d => height - yScale(d.percent))
```

On top of that (and this addresses your second question), you are using Bostock's [margin convention](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563) wrong. You should translate the `g` group according to the margins, and then appending all the bars to that translated group, without translating them again. Also, append the axes' groups to that `g` group.

All that being said, this is the code with those changes:

```js
const data = [{
    year: 2012,
    percent: 50
  },
  {
    year: 2013,
    percent: 30
  },
  {
    year: 2014,
    percent: 90
  },
  {
    year: 2015,
    percent: 60
  },
  {
    year: 2016,
    percent: 75
  },
  {
    year: 2017,
    percent: 20
  }
];

const height = 300;
const width = 370;
const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 25
};

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.year))
  .padding(0.2)
  .range([0, width - margin.right - margin.left]);

const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([height - margin.bottom - margin.top, 0]);

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("margin-left", 10);

const g = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

g
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", d => xScale(d.year))
  .attr("y", d => yScale(d.percent))
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", d => height - margin.bottom - margin.top - yScale(d.percent))
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")


g.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

g.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
  .attr(
    "transform",
    `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom - margin.top})`
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is possible to change the width for 100%?

Answer (score 0):

```
svg
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", d => xScale(d.year))
      .attr("y", d => height - yScale(100-d.percent))
      .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", d => yScale(100-d.percent))
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, -${margin.bottom})`);
```

You need to minus the percentage from 100

Working: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-microservice-8kjqd

Comment: Thank you, you can help with 2 question?

Comment: Yes tell me, It above solution works for you please accept the answer.

Comment: the second one is on the question

Comment: You mean that 100 is cutting on the top, you want to fix that?